# syncing products with d-stripe

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am having trouble syncing the products from my Stripe account to my django project. I've successfully synced the products, but I also inadvertently synced my entire stripe purchase and payment history to my django project.

I followed most of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@surya.vijjeswarapu/how-to-create-subscription-payments-with-django-and-stripe-3d-secure-using-dj-stripe-a7b55a391196) which describes how to set up stripe subscriptions on your django site using dj-stripe. When it came time to adding my products, the tutorial says to use this command:

python manage.py djstripe_sync_plans_from_stripe

But that command did not work for me. The command that did work for me was

python manage.py [djstripe_sync_models](https://dj-stripe.dev/usage/manually_syncing_with_stripe/)

This worked but it literally downloaded all of my stripe data and synced it to my django project, which was unnecessary. I just wanted to sync the subsription products that I created. How can I sync only the products from my stripe account?

Answer (score 0):

use this command for syncing only the Account model.

`python manage.py djstripe_sync_models Account`

`python manage.py djstripe_sync_models Account Charge`

Another command for syncing Customer:

`python manage.py djstripe_sync_customers`